# Integrating a function containing a wavelet

Tags: numerical-integration, wavelet-analysis

How do I evaluate the integral `c`?

```
u = -x^2 + 10 x
phiD6[x_] = WaveletPhi[DaubechiesWavelet[6], x]

c = Integrate[u phiD6[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: Thank you Prof. José Antonio Díaz Navas. This is the perfect solution.

Answer (score 6):

Here's how to get `Integrate[]` to work.

As you may have already noticed, the result of `WaveletPhi[DaubechiesWavelet[6], x]` is a `Piecewise[]` function containing an `InterpolatingFunction[]`. Since the integration interval is well within the domain of validity of the `InterpolatingFunction[]`, we can just extract that part and work with it:

```
dw6 = Head[Simplify[WaveletPhi[DaubechiesWavelet[6], x], 0 <= x <= 11]];
```

Let's check something out:

```
dw6["InterpolationOrder"]
   {1}
```

which tells us that the `InterpolatingFunction[]` is a **piecewise linear** interpolant, which makes things very easy. We just need to extract the points first:

```
pts = Transpose[{Flatten[dw6["Grid"]], dw6["ValuesOnGrid"]}];
```

From there, the strategy is to convert this into an explicit `Piecewise[]` object, which `Integrate[]` is equipped to handle:

```
pw[u_] = Piecewise[{InterpolatingPolynomial[#, u], #[[1, 1]] <= u < #[[2, 1]]} &
                    /@ Partition[pts, 2, 1]];
```

Now, we can compute the integral:

```
Integrate[(10 x - x^2) pw[x], {x, 0, 10}]
   11.911233499644986
```

This takes a while, tho. What we can do instead is to directly integrate over the pieces, and then add everything up at the end:

```
Total[Integrate[(10 x - x^2) InterpolatingPolynomial[#, x], {x, #[[1, 1]], #[[2, 1]]}] & /@
      Partition[Select[pts, 0 <= #[[1]] <= 10 &], 2, 1], 
      Method -> "CompensatedSummation"]
   11.911233499644995
```

Or, we can directly construct the closed-form expression for the integral of a single piece:

```
quad[{{x0_, y0_}, {x1_, y1_}}] = 
Simplify[Integrate[(10 x - x^2) InterpolatingPolynomial[{{x0, y0}, {x1, y1}}, x],
                   {x, x0, x1}]]

Total[quad /@ Partition[Select[pts, 0 <= #[[1]] <= 10 &], 2, 1],
      Method -> "CompensatedSummation"]
   11.911233499644984
```

which turns out to be the fastest method of all.

---

If, after all that, you still want to use `NIntegrate[]`, the right `Method` setting to use is `"InterpolationPointsSubdivision"`, which will split the `InterpolatingFunction[]` at its grid points, and integrate over all the pieces. Let's check something out first:

```
Length[pts] - 1
   2816
```

The reason I checked the number of points is that we need to set an option that will ensure the integration is necessarily done piece-by-piece:

```
Options[NIntegrate`InterpolationPointsSubdivision]
   {"MaxSubregions" -> 1000, "Method" -> "GlobalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 5}
```

So, we need to set `"MaxSubregions"` to be as high as the number of pieces, or greater. In addition, we can turn off `"SymbolicProcessing"`, since it's a polynomial at each piece, and we can use a quadrature method that is exact for polynomials of degree $2+1=3$. With all these considerations:

```
NIntegrate[(10 x - x^2) dw6[x], {x, 0, 10}, 
           Method -> {"InterpolationPointsSubdivision",
                      "MaxSubregions" -> 3000,
                      Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> 2}, 
                      "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]
   11.911233499644988
```

which is more accurate than the result from brute-forcing it with `"GlobalAdaptive"`.

Answer (score 5):

Try it with `NIntegrate`, as you want to obtain a numeric result. Further, `phiD6[x]`is a `Piecewise` function:

```
u = -x^2 + 10 x;
phiD6[x_] := WaveletPhi[DaubechiesWavelet[6], x];

NIntegrate[u phiD6[x], {x, 0, 10}, Method -> "GaussKronrodRule", AccuracyGoal -> 6, 
           MaxRecursion -> 20, WorkingPrecision -> 10]

(* 11.91115887 *)
```

The `GaussKronrodRule`, `AccuracyGoal`, `MaxRecursion`, and `WorkingPrecision` have been set to obtain a reliable and convergent numeric result. Moreover, an `Automatic` method could be used as well. However, you should maintain the other options, particularly, `MaxRecursion` (even with a lower value such as 10).

Answer (score 5):

When integrating an interpolating function, I think it's simplest to just use [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue):

```
NDSolveValue[{g'[x] == (-x^2 + 10 x) phiD6[x], g[0] == 0}, g[10], {x, 0, 10}]
```

> 11.9112