# Integral of a Wavelet function

Tags: numerical-integration, interpolation, wavelet-analysis

I ran into problems integrating a function which contains both an `If` condition and a `Wavelet` which is an `InterpolatingFunction` knowing that the values of Phi are very small

```
ϕ:= WaveletPhi[DaubechiesWavelet[8],x]:
Dϕ:=Dt[ϕ[t],{t,1}];
derPhi[x_?NumericQ]:=If[x>= 0 && x<= 15,Dϕ[x],0];
NIntegrate[derPhi[x],{x,0.25,0.5}];
```

Comment: Ayoub, please check that my translation still faithfully represents your original question.

Comment: I'd replace `If` with `Piecewise` since the latter is better suited for numeric functions while the former is intended more for programmatic use.

Answer (score 3):

You introduce an unnecessary dummy variable `x`.  This is my version

```
ϕ := WaveletPhi[DaubechiesWavelet[8]];
Dϕ := Derivative[1][ϕ];
derPhi[x_?NumericQ] := If[x >= 0 && x <= 15, Dϕ[x], 0];
NIntegrate[derPhi[x], {x, 0.25, 0.5}]

(* 0.00972165 *)
```

The numerical integration warns about slow convergence, presumably this is because of its many small discontinuities.

Is there a reason why you are differentiating and then integrating?  Can't you just work with the original function?

```
ϕ[0.5] - ϕ[0.25]
(* 0.00972164 *)
```

Comment: Basically the integration is multiplication of many functions That i didn't montion.
so the error shown is related to derPhi

Answer (score 3):

The approach taken in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/169462) is also applicable to this problem.

Construct the function to be integrated:

```
derPhi = Head[Simplify[D[WaveletPhi[DaubechiesWavelet[8], x], x], 0 < x < 15]]
```

Verify that we have a piecewise linear interpolant:

```
derPhi["InterpolationOrder"]
   {1}
```

This means, we can use a low-order quadrature rule to evaluate (sub-)integrals between the interpolation points.

Verify how many interpolation points are used in the integration interval of interest:

```
Count[Flatten[derPhi["Grid"]], x_ /; 1/4 < x < 1/2]
   63
```

We can then use the `"InterpolationPointsSubdivision"` method of `NIntegrate[]`. The count above is well within the default setting of `"MaxSubregions"`, so that doesn't need to be adjusted:

```
NIntegrate[derPhi[x], {x, 1/4, 1/2}, 
           Method -> {"InterpolationPointsSubdivision", 
                      Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> 2}, 
                      "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]
   0.009721637451048174
```